# Size of a struct datatype

Tags: c++

```
struct node
{
int value;
node *next=NULL;
};

node *foo;
foo = new node;

cout<< "\nsize of node: " << sizeof(foo);
cout<< "\nsize of node->value: " << sizeof(foo->val);
cout<< "\nsize of node->next: " << sizeof(foo->next);
```

**Output**

```
size of node: 8 bytes
size of node->val: 4 bytes
size of node->next: 8 bytes
```

The above snippet is for Singly Linked List.
The size of **node** based on its contents are  4 + 8 = 12 bytes. Then how its size is 8 bytes ?. I cant understand the concept behind this.

Comment: `sizeof(foo)` doesn't do what you think it does. You get the size of a pointer variable.

Comment: Do `sizeof(node)` instead.

Comment: hint: `foo` is not a `node`...

Comment: `sizeof *foo == sizeof (node)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(foo)` returns the size of a pointer variable (since you declared `foo` as `node *foo`), which is only 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine or 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Size of node (a struct) and size foo (a pointer variable) should not be same.**

Pointer stores the address of a variable, not the variable.
So, the size of pointer means the size of address-variable; and it depends on platform and/or architecture.

1. In practice, pointers size is 2 on a 16-bit system, 4 on a 32-bit system, 8 on a 64-bit system (not always true).
2. And usually, on a specific platform the size of any type of pointer (char/int/void/... ) equal to size of integer (not always true).

Sometimes, You will get the mix (1, 2) result.

In my PC (Configuration : System Type   x64-based PC, 64-bit Operating System, IDE visual studio 2015, Code::Blocks 13.12) it is showing as below:

size of node: 8

size of foo: 4

size of node->value: 4

size of node->next: 4